# use bootstrap to affix button on right of container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use affix of bootstrap 3.

Its working fine but i need to do the button affix right to container not to window.

The problem i am facing is when i Ctrl-- to reduce screen size button get stick on right of window.(facing problem on large screen)

How can i stick button to right of container.so when screen size get large it display right to container.

Here is link: [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/d9UP7/)

```
.save-btn .affix {
  top: 100px;
  right: 0px;

}
.container {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
                    <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="save-btn">
                    <button name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn   btn-orange btn-lg affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">Save </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle is using BS 2.x, but your markup is for Bootstrap 3.

I created a Bootply (which includes BS 3 automatically): http://www.bootply.com/95296

I think you want to use `pull-right` and not `affix` to pull the button to the right.